# 'going for me' vs. 'going instead of me'

Tags: expressions

Is this phrase correct?

> They will be going ***for*** me.

or can you use this wording?

> They will be going ***instead of*** me.

Is either expression usage correct, or it needs to follow some rules?

Comment: 'They will be going for me' means (in most cases) 'They will be going on my behalf' (and would usually imply attending a meeting, doing an errand, visiting a sick relative etc). 'They will be going instead of me' does not necessarily mean 'on my behalf', just 'in my place'. They may have just booked the last places on the tour I wanted to go on.

Comment: You haven't explained what you are trying to convey.  I would not normally think of "going for me" meaning either "instead of me" or "on my behalf", but rather one of the meanings given in Deadrat's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although context will help, the idiom *going for me* has three meanings that may prove confusing. The first is to attack. From [*Stormwalker*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7I9hbvFbSwwC&pg=PT88&dq=%22was%20going%20for%20me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj1feNjJfOAhWypYMKHasXCsAQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=%22was%20going%20for%20me%22&f=false) by A James:

> [Fremont said] "It should have been me that died, not Charlie."
>
> "No one should have died," I said in a firm voice. "If you want to
>   blame someone, blame me. The skinwalker<sup>*</sup> was **going for me** and missed."

The second meaning is the unfolding of events. From *Through the Eyes: An Adventure in Nogales* by T K DuGan:

> Chino asked how everything was **going for me**. Was today my first
>   day in Nogales? How long would I be staying?

The third meaning is favorable circumstances. From [*Sunshine for the Latter-Day Saint Teenager's Soul*](https://books.google.com/books?id=bL1nRgshZJIC&q=%22going%20for%20me%22&dq=%22going%20for%20me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijwbOqj5fOAhVMOSYKHcfDDcIQ6AEIPTAF) by J Blytheway:

> As a teenager I felt I had a lot **going for me**: I had a wonderful
>   family, I maintained good grades, I had good friends, and I was very
>   involved in school extracurricular activities.

If you want to convey the idea that someone is going to act on your behalf, it might be better to say "going in my stead" or "going in my place".

*A skinwalker is a Navajo witch.

Comment: dr sir I have messaged you there on englishforums. Thank you. Waiting there. Gargi.